# Return text when looking up data

Tags: excel, match, lookup, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet which looks like this:

```
Name      Task              Date
Mike      Go to the beach   10/1/13
Mike      Go Shopping       10/2/13
Mike      Go to work        10/3/13
Bill      Go Hiking         10/1/13
Bill      Go to work        10/3/13
```

I am trying to build another tab to the spreadsheet which will look at the data tab and return the matching text value when the rows and the columns match.

I'm trying to use a formula create a type of pivot table.

The results should look like this:

```
Name  10/1/13          10/2/13      10/3/13
Mike  Go to the beach  Go shopping  Go to work
Bill  Go Hiking       *Blank*       Go to work
```

I tried to post images but couldn't since this is my first post.
I hope you can understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in Pivot Tables, I have done it the dumb way - but works. Assumptions:

1) Source Data always on "Sheet1" with those 3 column headers

2) The "Sheet2" will be used to store sorted data

```
Sub SO_19105503()
    Const NameCol As Long = 1
    Const TaskCol As Long = 2
    Const DateCol As Long = 3

    Dim oShSrc As Worksheet, oShTgt As Worksheet, R As Long, C As Long
    Dim aNames As Variant, aDates As Variant
    Dim lNames As Long, lDates As Long
    Dim oRng As Range, oArea As Range

    Set oShSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Source worksheet with original data
    oShSrc.Copy Before:=oShSrc
    Set oShSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 (2)") ' Copy of Source worksheet
    Set oShTgt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Target worksheet to store sorted data
    oShSrc.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Get unique names (sorted) in column A
    aNames = Array()
    lNames = 0
    R = 1
    oShSrc.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=oShSrc.Cells(R, NameCol), Header:=xlYes
    Do
        R = R + 1
        If Not IsEmpty(oShSrc.Cells(R, NameCol)) And oShSrc.Cells(R, NameCol).Value <> oShSrc.Cells(R - 1, NameCol).Value Then
            ReDim Preserve aNames(lNames)
            aNames(lNames) = oShSrc.Cells(R, NameCol).Value
            lNames = lNames + 1
        End If
    Loop Until IsEmpty(oShSrc.Cells(R, NameCol))
    ' Get unique dates (sorted) in column C
    aDates = Array()
    lDates = 0
    R = 1
    oShSrc.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=oShSrc.Cells(R, DateCol), Header:=xlYes
    Do
        R = R + 1
        If Not IsEmpty(oShSrc.Cells(R, DateCol)) And oShSrc.Cells(R, DateCol).Value <> oShSrc.Cells(R - 1, DateCol).Value Then
            ReDim Preserve aDates(lDates)
            aDates(lDates) = oShSrc.Cells(R, DateCol).Value
            lDates = lDates + 1
        End If
    Loop Until IsEmpty(oShSrc.Cells(R, DateCol))
    ' Prepare and put data to Target sheet
    oShTgt.Range("A1").Value = oShSrc.Range("A1").Value ' Name
    ' Insert Dates (start from column B on Row 1)
    For C = 0 To lDates - 1
        oShTgt.Cells(1, C + 2).Value = aDates(C)
    Next
    ' Insert Names (start from Row 2 on Column A)
    For R = 0 To lNames - 1
        oShTgt.Cells(R + 2, 1).Value = aNames(R)
    Next
    ' Reprocess the source data with Autofilter
    For R = 0 To lNames - 1
        oShSrc.AutoFilterMode = False ' Remove AutoFilter before apply
        ' Apply AutoFilter with Criteria of R'th entry in array aNames
        oShSrc.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & aNames(R)
        ' Go through Ranges in each Area
        For Each oArea In oShSrc.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            For Each oRng In oArea.Rows
                ' Stop checking if row is more than used
                If oRng.Row > oShSrc.UsedRange.Rows.count Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                ' Check only if the row is below the header
                If oRng.Row > 1 Then
                    For C = 0 To lDates - 1
                        ' Find the matching date and put the "Task" value
                        If oShSrc.Cells(oRng.Row, DateCol).Value = aDates(C) Then
                            oShTgt.Cells(R + 2, C + 2).Value = oShSrc.Cells(oRng.Row, TaskCol).Value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next C
                End If
            Next oRng
        Next oArea
    Next R
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    oShSrc.Delete ' Delete the temporary data source sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set oShSrc = Nothing
    Set oShTgt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Screenshots - Source Data/Result:

[image: SourceData] [image]